# How to handle remotely signals using gdb?

Tags: gdb, gdbserver

I want to debug program remotely. But the issue is my program is using signals.
On local machine I handle signal using following command:
`handle SIG64 nostop noprint` 
But for remotely debugging using gdbserver , I don't know how to handle signals.
Here is what I am doing:

```
remote$ gdbserver :2345 hello_world
Process hello_world created; pid = 2509
Listening on port 2345

local$ gdb -q hello_world
Reading symbols from /home/user/hello_world...done.
(gdb) target remote 192.168.0.11:2345
Remote debugging using 192.168.0.11:2345
0x002f3850 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux.so.2
(gdb) continue
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks & BR,
Yuvi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `handle SIG64 nostop noprint` command should work remotely just as well.

Comment: there were 2 Signals SIG32 SIG64, I don't from where SIG32 comes. I have only used SIG64. Anyways after handling SIG32 as well its working fine.